# Find all substrings which are repeated

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

I need to find all substring of length greater than 2 which are repeated.
I can solve it using brute force .Is there any other optimal solution available?

```
eg . SpringisHereAgainSpringHere
Sample output : Spr,Spri,Spring,here,her
```

Comment: A common data-structure to use for this is a suffix array. Maybe read on it and you might be able to figure it out yourself

Comment: Would in "arara" the substring "ara" be considered as repeating?

Comment: yes it would be repeated